# Connecting to website without curl or bash

Tags: bash, shell, curl, get

I'm trying to connect to a website like this `"examplesite.com:9000/link"` using a method like this:

```
echo -e "GET http://google.com HTTP/1.0\n\n" | nc google.com 80 > /dev/null 2>&1
```

I've seen people ping google with the above code.
I can use `curl` or `wget` to go to that site but I don't wanna use those methods because I'm using a microcontroller that doesn't support `curl` or `wget`.

Could someone explain how the above code is working?

Comment: Do you know what the `nc` utility is? Have you looked it up? Do you know how the `HTTP` protocol works? Have you looked it up?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. `nc` opens a connection to port 80 on `google.com`
2. The `echo` statement is a valid GET request, using HTTP/1.0 protocol
3. `> /dev/null 2>&1` redirects both `stdout` and `stderr`, producing no output
4. You can tell success by the exit code, in `$?` (value of 0 means success)

You could write this shorter:

```
echo -e "GET /\n\n" | nc google.com 80
```

And more portable (without `echo -e`):

```
printf "GET /\n\n" | nc google.com 80
```

Or more portable but still with `echo`:

```
{ echo GET /; echo; } | nc google.com 80
```

Comment: what if there is an address like "example.com:9000/link" would i put the /link after? so for instance would it look like  

echo -e "GET /\n\n" | nc google.com 80/link ?

Comment: `printf "GET /link\n\n" | nc example.com 9000`

Comment: what if nc is not installed?